# how to call restTemplate.postForEntity when entity is having different field name than expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am having a rest API which accept entity with field names as id,title. But when calling I am having different fields with same value as id,description.

How to modify the call so that I can make the request.

In the below code, Employee class is having two fields id, desc which are different from id,title.

```
public ResponseEntity<Employee> postForEntity(Employee newEmployee) {
  MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("User-Agent", "EmployeeRestClient demo class");
  headers.add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
  HttpEntity<Employee> entity = new HttpEntity<>(newEmployee, headers);
  return restTemplate.postForEntity(REQUEST_URI, entity, Employee.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that if the class *Employee* is correct on this place. If correct, then map Java properties to JSON as follows:

```
public class Employee {
    ... id; // name remains unchanged

    @JsonProperty("title")
    ... desc;

}
```

If you cannot modify *Employee* class, create another one with needed property names and copy instance of *Employee* to your instance of your class, and then user this instance in the *restTemplate*.

Comment: I agree with what @mentallurg is saying, just like to add a small comment (for a better practice) is that usually you want your rest apis to have their own request/response rather than expose your db entities